# How do I update the IcedTea Plugin on 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, java, google-chrome, icedtea, runescape

Whenever I open up the page http://www.runescape.com/game.ws? in google chrome I get the notice, "IcedTea was blocked because it is out of date" and gives me the two options of updating it or running this time.

I've gone to the link attached to the option of updating it and its a wikipedia page http://icedtea.classpath.org/wiki/Main_Page that wasn't helpful for me because I didn't know what to download and install.

Whenever I click, 'Run this time' it works momentarily but it is prone to have the runescape interface in the browser disappear and be replaced with a black screen.

Comment: Same here... any page that needs java plugin will fail to load at first, I need to press "run this time" every time... Annoying, to say the least. I've been testing with icedtea 7, using `update-alternatives --config java` but still stuck here

Comment: I have 12.10 and `icedtea-7-plugin` package installed. I get no error on Your link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Ubuntu 12.10 is not supported anymore. Update to 13.10 or "downgrade" to 12.04 LTS.
Secondly, the Icedtea plugin can be installed by running the following command in terminal: "`sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin`"

After that just enter your password and press "Y" for yes to install.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Assembler-Tools/IcedTea-31533.shtml and download this after removing it in the app store.

Hope this helps ,
Bob

Answer (score -1):

updated icedtea-plugin is available at: 
(http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/quantal/main/base/icedtea-plugin)

It is also available at Ubuntu Software Center as stand alone and OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime add-ons.